# Two questions on one sentence from »Der Spiegel«

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, german-to-english, pronoun

The two below paragraphs come from the article “[Kehrtwende der Bundesregierung. Plötzlich hart gegen Erdogan](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/recep-tayyip-erdogan-bei-g20-warum-die-bundesregierung-seinen-auftritt-verbieten-will-a-1155035.html)” in *Der Spiegel*. My questions refer to the sentence highlighted in **bold** in the second paragraph. The first paragraph is given for context purposes.

> Und auch Erdogan selbst durfte mehrmals in Deutschland vor seinen
>   Anhängern sprechen - zuletzt 2015. Im Sommer vergangenen Jahres
>   allerdings, kurz nach dem Putschversuch, scheiterte er mit seinem
>   Versuch, sich über eine Live-Schalte an Deutsch-Türken zu richten.
>   Auch damals aber schritt nicht der Bund ein, sondern die Kölner
>   Polizei. Deren Präsident verbot, dass Erdogan bei einer
>   Großveranstaltung der AKP-Lobbyorganisation UETD in der Stadt über
>   Video auf einer Leinwand zu seinen Anhängern sprechen konnte. Ein
>   Gericht hatte diese Maßnahme später für rechtens erklärt.
>
> Diesmal will Berlin selbst handeln, die Botschaft in Richtung Ankara
>   setzen. **Ganz sicher, dass sie einen Auftritt Erdogans in Deutschland
>   verhindern kann, kann die Bundesregierung aber nicht sein.** Denkbar
>   wäre, dass der türkische Präsident sich entschließt, statt in der
>   Öffentlichkeit etwa auf quasi-türkischem Boden in Hamburg zu sprechen
>   - wie im Frühjahr schon Cavusoglu. Dann aber vor deutlich weniger Menschen als in einer Arena oder großen Halle.

First question: What does sie refer to (**Ganz sicher, dass *sie*...**)? Berlin is neuter; Ankara is neuter; the verb kann (**verhindern *kann***) indicates that neither Berlin nor Ankara is used in generalized terms to mean German or Turkish government (in which case plural can be warranted). And *Botschaft* and *Richtung* cannot on their own *verhindern* anything. So, I don't understand what *sie* refers to.

Second question: What does *kann die Bundesregierung aber nicht sein* mean? With regards to my understanding of this part of the sentence, it would be justifiable to say: It's Greek to me.

Answer (score 12):

With different word order:

> Die Bundesregierung kann nicht ganz sicher sein, dass sie einen Auftritt Erdogans in Deutschland verhindern kann.

The *sie* refers to *die Bundesregierung*. I hope that this also clarifies the meaning.

(Theoretically, *sie* could also refer to *die Botschaft*. In that case I would expect *diese* instead of *sie*, though. Also, it makes less sense.)

Comment: On "Botschaft": I am fairly certain that the correct translation would be "message", not "embassy" in this case, which would lead to a "sie"->"Botschaft" reference making even less sense.

Comment: @TAR86, sure. I was thinking that they are sending a message but that may not change anything.

Answer (score 4):

It's simple: "*Sie*" is "*die Bundesregierung*" itself.

Let's change the sentence a little bit:

> Die Bundesregierung kann nicht ganz sicher sein, dass sie einen Auftritt Erdogans in Deutschland verhindern kann.

"The German government can not be sure, that they can prevent an Erdogan's public appearance in Germany".